# C# Convert List<T> to multidimensional float

Tags: c#

I have a list of Vector3 structs like this

```
List<Vector3> cloud
```

I want to convert this list into a 3 dimensional float array

```
float[,,] points
```

Where Vector3 is a struct of 3 floats ( x, y, z )

The points array should be a 3 dimensional float array containing each

```
float[Vector3.X, Vector3.Y, Vector3.Z]
```

in the cloud list. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you want your output data to look like? Let's say I give you a list with 3 vectors: (0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8). What are the dimensions of the output array, and what values would you expect to find at each index?

Comment: @DMGregory float[3][3][3] = {{0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}}. The first dimension holds all x values, the second y values and the third z values

Comment: You've misunderstood dimensions. What you've shown here is a 2-dimensional array. The inner dimension addresses which vector in the list, the outer dimension addresses which component in the vector (0=x, 1=y, 2=z). There is no third array dimension in the example you've shown.

Comment: @DMGregory alright since you asked for that extra pair of brackets 
float[1, 3, 3] { { { 0, 3, 6 }, { 1, 4, 7 }, { 2, 5, 8 } } }; The idea is to have a 3d grid of cells where each cell has x,y,z values from the list

Comment: What are you using the outermost dimension for? As currently stated, you could capture all the same data and access patterns with a 2D array.

Comment: So I'm also a bit confused in what you want, but my guess is that you want to access your data in a specific way, for which you need this multidimensional float you describe, correct? If so, is this the way you want to access your data? `Vector3 example = points[xIndex, yIndex, zIndex]` where x,y and z index represent the index that the Vector3 would have in the cloud array/List? If this is not the way how you want to access it, could you add an example to your question on how you do want to access your data and what you expect the result to be given an example original cloud list?